# Unity - Load Lightmaps at Runtime

Tags: unity, lighting, lightmap

I'm a bit of a novice to lighting, but I think what I want to do is possible, so please bear with me.

Due to the nature of my game, I've taken an approach where a singular scene `game` is where all of the gameplay occurs.

For each level, I'm arranging all the `GameObject`s and `Terrain` in a secondary scene (named `testbed`) to my liking. Once I've got it to my liking, I save that to a prefab, which in turn is saved to an `AssetBundle`. I also generate the lighting at this point, which I can see appear in my project under a `Assets/Scenes/testbed/` folder.

At runtime, a script in the `game` scene reads the appropriate `AssetBundle`, and then loads & positions all of my objects and characters. Everything about this works, **except** for updating the lighting.

My approach is to store references to the lighting textures that have been output into the aforementioned `testbed` folder via a `ScriptableObject` (after trying and failing to use the `LightingData` object that appearred in this same folder):

[image: scriptable object for lighting]

Then, when I'm loading my level up into the `game` scene, this block is executed:

```
    public void LoadLighting(LevelKey key)
    {
        var data = levelMap.metaData.Find(it => it.key == key);
        var directions = data.lightData.directions;
        var lights = data.lightData.lights;

        var lightmaps = new LightmapData[directions.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < directions.Length && i < lights.Length; i++)
        {
            var lightmapData = new LightmapData();
            lightmapData.lightmapDir = directions[i];
            lightmapData.lightmapColor = lights[i];

            lightmaps[i] = lightmapData;
        }

        LightmapSettings.lightmaps = lightmaps;
    }
```

Based on a lot of searching, this should cause *something* to happen, but I can't detect any change in the scene.

Does what I'm trying make any sense? Should I just scrap this and make dozens of different scenes (which I'm trying to avoid) instead? Really any advice here is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid multiple scenes? That seems no more convoluted than your current workflow with prefabs.

Comment: @DMGregory good question - I think I avoided it subconsciously since the last time I worked on a similarly structured game (using Unity 4), the prefab tools were a lot less fleshed out, and I ended up having to manually make dozens of edits in individual scenes. I should probably switch back, but I thought I should see if the above possible given I'm already at this point.

Comment: @DMGregory also, most of the info I could find on this topic is from Unity Answers 3 - 5 years ago, and wanted to create a record on stack exchange if possible.

Comment: Additive scene loading and multi-scene editing in modern versions of the engine should help with those aspects.